# How can I create a single executable for Playwright tests

Tags: playwright, pkg

Is it possible to create a single executable from a Playwright test using PKG or something similar ?

`pkg` requires a command line such as

```
pkg index.js
```

but to run Playwright tests one would use `npx playwright test.js`

How would one use pkg to create a single executable that will automatically run the scrip ?

Comment: Do you mean `npx playwright test`? It's a bit strange to create an executable to run tests. Why do you want to do that--what advantage would there be for anyone? If `npx playwright test` is too complex to run, use a macro on your shell or package.json rather than going into a slow, nonportable and (probably) unnecessary exe build.

Comment: We want a standard test app to run on multiple devices and want to avoid having to install node + all the test components and scripts on each device.  The browser app interacts with devices on the computer so this is to validate the configuration of the whole device.  And yes "npx playwright test"

Comment: Are you looking for something like this?
https://github.com/rgl/playwright-standalone

Comment: @sahmeepee - that's a start thanks, I'll take a look